# what the torque should be on my 2000 gmc 4.3 intake maanifold

Tags: chevrolet, air-intake, intake-manifold

I need to know the torque on intake manifold bolts on 2000 gmc Sonoma with a 4.3 motor

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help.  I note that it is a very specific sequence and three-stage endeavor -- which makes me suspect that it should probably be followed:

[image]